# BigQueryIO loads not offloading rows to GCS when early trigger occurs

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm playing around with BigQueryIO write using loads. My load trigger is set to 18 hours. I'm ingesting data from Kafka with a fixed daily window.

Based on https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/v2.2.0/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BatchLoads.java#L213-L231 it seems that the intended behavior is to offload rows to the filesystem when at least 500k records are in a pane

I managed to produce ~ 600K records and waited for around 2 hours to see if the rows were uploaded to gcs, however, nothing was there. I noticed that the "GroupByDestination" step in "BatchLoads" shows 0 under "Output collections" size.

When I use a smaller load trigger all seems fine. Shouldn't the `AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(FILE_TRIGGERING_RECORD_COUNT))))` be triggered?

Here is the code for writing to BigQuery

```
  BigQueryIO
  .writeTableRows()
  .to(new SerializableFunction[ValueInSingleWindow[TableRow], TableDestination]() {
    override def apply(input: ValueInSingleWindow[TableRow]): TableDestination = {
      val startWindow = input.getWindow.asInstanceOf[IntervalWindow].start()
      val dayPartition = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd").withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC).print(startWindow)
      new TableDestination("myproject_id:mydataset_id.table$" + dayPartition, null)
    }
  })
  .withMethod(Method.FILE_LOADS)
  .withCreateDisposition(CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
  .withWriteDisposition(WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
  .withSchema(BigQueryUtils.schemaOf[MySchema])
  .withTriggeringFrequency(Duration.standardHours(18))
  .withNumFileShards(10)
```

The job id is 2018-02-16_14_34_54-7547662103968451637. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you include the part of your pipeline's code where it invokes BigQueryIO.write(), with all the configuration it supplies to it? I'm particularly interested in whether you're writing to a single table or using dynamic destinations.

Comment: Hello, I've updated the post to include BigQueryIO settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Panes are per key per window, and BigQueryIO.write() with dynamic destinations uses the destination as key under the hood, so the "500k elements in pane" thing applies per destination per window.

Comment: That did it. Using a fixed destination worked. Thanks

Comment: You may be glad to know that what you're doing (loading time-partitioned data) can now be done much faster and cheaper. A PR for support of this in BigQueryIO is in review and will be merged to master soon https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/4694